# getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

```
String lastName = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select last_name from t_actor where id = ?", new Object[]{1212L}, String.class);
```

I got the above line while searching for code to  get data from sql using jdbc templates. I was wondering what **`new Object[]{1212L}`** means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the input parameter for the `?`, in this case the number 1212.  Typically this would be derived from some user input or other data, and not hardcoded in the query.

Answer (score 6):

Each "?" in the query represents a SQL parameter.  The Object array represents the values to be used for the parameters. In this case, there is only one parameter hence the single value.  The "L" specifies a literal of type long, in case you're not familiar with that syntax.